# How to generate 7 random numbers, without repeats

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I want to generate 7 random numbers from 0 to 39 and store them in one dimensional array. I must make sure each number is different (can't have two 7s for example).

I thought about shuffling numbers, but I only need 7 out of 40. I actually have to do this in school and we haven't covered pointers yet and we're using rand() function to get random numbers. I guess the solution doesn't have to be truly random, but at least somewhat.

Comment: *I thought about shuffling numbers* That was a good thought, you should use it.  So what if you waste 32 ints worth of space. It's simple, easy and can be done in like 3 lines of code.

Comment: I would shuffle a vector containing the numbers 0..39 (with `std::shuffle`) and then pick the first 7.

Comment: Marginally related: [Rand Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful). This is long and worth watching, but if you're only interested in why `rand` is a bad idea, the presenter beats that to death in the first 10 minutes or so. But since  that's kind-of useless without presenting an alternative, there's the other 20 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

OK, here's my contribution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector <int> v (40);
    std::generate (v.begin (), v.end (), [n = 0] () mutable { return n++; });

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g (rd ());
    std::shuffle (v.begin (), v.end (), g);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
        std::cout << v [i] << '\n';
}
```

Representative output:

```
5
39
10
17
36
11
31
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hKO8dsEaVEkNwgo8)

**Edit:** As noted by skeller, the call to `std::generate` can be replaced by:

```
std::iota (v.begin (), v.end (), 0);
```

which is a lot neater.

Also `std::vector v (40);` can be replaced by `std::array <int, 40> v;` if you prefer.

Comment: If the initial set was not 40, but much, much larger, do you consider it smart to shuffle a massive set, just to select 7 elements?  Better to select random elements from a large set.

Comment: @abelenky Well, that was not the question.  I did not downvote you by the way, so your (presumed) downvote of my answer seems a little petty.

Comment: Slow algorithms are *never* correct.

Comment: nice answer, can be improved by using std::iota instead of generate with the lambda :)

Comment: @abelenky for the given size this is not slow, for bigger range one would also not use your solution, but rather just generate a new random value in the given range in case of a collision. this solution is appropriate for the given problem

Comment: @skeller Added a reference to std::iota to my answer, thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Would instead use set (or unordered set) to detect duplicates. More idiot proof. Also we can throw in bloom filter just for fun sake.

Comment: `iota(...1)` will generate values 1-40.  The problem called for 0-39.

Comment: @abelenky Good spot.  Edited my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It was noted in comments that it's important to teach the modern way of doing randoms. So here's my take :

**Modern C++ approach**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> AllValues(40) ; // Vector of 40 integers
  std::iota (std::begin(AllValues), std::end(AllValues), 0); // Fill AllValues with 0..39
  std::random_device RandomDevice; // Create a random device
  std::default_random_engine RandomEngine(RandomDevice()); // Create a random engine, seeding from RandomDevice  
  std::shuffle(std::begin(AllValues), std::end(AllValues), RandomEngine);  // Shuffle AllValues using RandomEngine
  std::vector<int> RandomNumbers(AllValues.begin(), AllValues.begin() + 7); // Create a new vector using the first 7 numbers of AllValues

  // Display the 7 random values
  for (auto i: RandomNumbers)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;  

  return 0;
}
```

---

That being said, if I get your vibe, you're more looking to learn how it's done rather than a "correct and modern" answer.

Let's look at the parameters of what you're asking.

You need to generate 7 random numbers in an array, makeing sure than none of the value appear twice. Since the odds of selecting twice the same random numbers are low (6 / 40 [15%] for the 7th number), I'd do it using two loops. That'll always work, and will take the least amount of memory without golfing it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

// Those defines could be constants
#define NB_RANDOM_NUMBERS (7)
#define RAND_MODULO (40)

int main()
{
  std::random_device seeder;  // Obtain a seed for the random number engine
  std::mt19937 generator(seeder()); // mersenne_twister_engine seeded with seeder()
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> randomizer(0, RAND_MODULO-1);


  int RandomNumbers[NB_RANDOM_NUMBERS]; // the array that'll get the random numbers

  // A loop for all seven random numbers
  for(int numberIndex = 0; numberIndex < NB_RANDOM_NUMBERS; numberIndex++)
  {
    bool found; // indicates if we found the new number in a previous iteration
    do
    {
      // Generate a new random number
      RandomNumbers[numberIndex] = randomizer(generator);
      /*
      *** If using rand() is required : ***
      RandomNumbers[numberIndex] = rand() % RAND_MODULO;
      */

      // Check if it was found or not in a previous iteration
      found = false;
      for(int checkNumber = 0; checkNumber < numberIndex && !found; checkNumber++)
      {
        // Is the new number already in the array?
        if(RandomNumbers[checkNumber] == RandomNumbers[numberIndex])
        {
          // Exit the loop and restart over
          found = true;
        }
      }
    }
    while(found);

    cout << numberIndex+1 << " : " << RandomNumbers[numberIndex] << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Note that the closer `NB_RANDOM_NUMBERS-1` gets to `RAND_MODULO`, the longest this algorithm will run. For example, if you want to generate 90 randoms numbers from a pool of 100, the last random number will have 89% chance of being already in `RandomNumbers` array. The inner loop will probably run for a long time, and the algorithm won't be efficient.

In that case, it's more efficient to fill an array of all values and select them at random :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

#define NB_RANDOM_NUMBERS (7)
#define RAND_MODULO (40)

int main()
{
  std::random_device seeder;  // Obtain a seed for the random number engine
  std::mt19937 generator(seeder()); // mersenne_twister_engine seeded with seeder()
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> randomizer(0, RAND_MODULO-1);

  int RandomNumbers[NB_RANDOM_NUMBERS]; // the array that'll get the random numbers
  int AllValues[RAND_MODULO]; // a array of all numeric values to chose from

  for(int i = 0; i < RAND_MODULO; i++)
  {
    AllValues[i] = i;
  }

  // A loop for all seven random numbers
  for(int numberIndex = 0; numberIndex < NB_RANDOM_NUMBERS; numberIndex++)
  {
    int randomIndex;

    // Search for a random index that doesn't contain -1
    do
    {
      randomIndex = randomizer(generator);
    }
    while(AllValues[randomIndex] == -1);

    // Assign the number at the random index you generated
    RandomNumbers[numberIndex] = AllValues[randomIndex];
    // Set it to -1 in preparation of the next iteration
    AllValues[randomIndex] = -1;

    cout << numberIndex+1 << " : " << RandomNumbers[numberIndex] << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: to make it modern, please do not use #define and use std::array (or vector) instead of the c-style array

Comment: I'd simply use std::set<int> to fill the numbers and then store its elements into an array. This way it is a single loop. It is also more efficient when desired number of elements in the output set is large.

Comment: The OP stated that the number should be in a one-dimensional array. I'm assuming they haven't seen vectors yet, or they would have mentioned it. Also, the OP didn't ask for the modernest answer. It could be easily achieved using a `std::set` and `std::shuffle`, but I suspect that they're still learning basic algoritms, and that would kind of defeat the purpose of learning how to do it from scratch. If the OP doesn't like the answer, I don't mind.

Comment: @skeller I added a moderner approach.

Comment: @MartinVéronneau the last one looks way nicer :)

Answer (score 0):

A C++ version of my same algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g (rd ());

    std::vector <int> v(40);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);  // Fill the vector with values 0-39

    std::vector<int> output(7);
    std::generate(output.begin(), output.end(),
        [v,g]()mutable
        {
            auto pos = v.begin() + (g()%v.size());    // Pick an element at random (by iterator)
            int value = *pos;                         // Get the value of random element
            iter_swap(pos, v.begin() + v.size() - 1); // Swap the random element to the end of vector
            v.pop_back();                             // Erase the last element of vector (the random element)
            return value;                             // Return the randomly chosen value
        });

    for (auto& x :  output) std::cout << x << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: erasing on a vector causes all the following elements to be moved. So for picking k numbers from a range of n, this has a complexity of O(k * n), plus you make a full copy of v when capturing in the lambda.
apart from that: solid approach

Comment: Good point.  I improved the complexity by swapping the element to the end of the vector, then erasing the last element of the vector.

Comment: the copy in the capture can be avoided by [v2 = std::move(v)] when using C++14 or newer :)

Comment: Is this a good point to mention that the simple C version is shorter, faster, more memory efficient, and easier to understand?

Comment: yes, because you know how to do it properly in C. But the next lay person might try a bigger array, exceed stack size, move it to heap with new, mess up the delete, ... we all have seen and cleaned up such code.

Answer (score -1):

This works by selecting random elements from an array, and shortening the array to remove the selected element.

Comments and explanation inline:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int array[40];
    for(int i=0;i<40; ++i) array[i]=i;  // Fill an array 0-39, in order.

    int output[7];
    for(int i=0; i<7; ++i)
    {
        int rnd_index = rand()%(40-i);    // Pick a random index in the array.
        output[i] = array[rnd_index];     // Copy randomly selected value to the output array
        array[rnd_index] = array[40-i-1]; // Copy the last item in the array to the randomly selected item, effectively removing the selected item from the pool
    }

    // Show the output
    for(int i=0; i<7; ++i) printf("[%d] : %d\n", i, output[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 9424KB
[0] : 23
[1] : 22
[2] : 3
[3] : 9
[4] : 5
[5] : 10
[6] : 20
```

Note, there is a slight selection bias in using rand() and modulo operation.
If you need a more perfectly flat distribution, that will need improvement.

Comment: Why use `rand`? We have [better](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) options these days.

Comment: Because it is short to write, and easily understood.  The method of RNG is not important.

Comment: you could *at least* seed it (`srand`).

Comment: That adds nothing to illustrating the *stated* problem.   I *could* add error checking, out-of-memory handling, exception catching, etc.  But the point is to clearly illustrate a solution to the problem, not provide a perfect program.

Comment: The problem is that the "solution" will be copy-n-pasted by clueless newbies and cargo-cult programmers. So it should reflect best practices, not just something that works in a narrow interpretation. It will be used/abused by people who don't know how to fix the flaws. So it should be bullet proof, if possible (IMHO).

Comment: this will not give the randomness as the proper modern options give. we should teach modern c++ to the newcomers, not old C-style.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I highly doubt that other newbies will look for "How to generate 7 random numbers, without repeats" The title kinda kills it for broader use and only OP will use the answer.